# Trouble with formating multicols

Tags: multicol, columnbreak

I have some trouble with tho code below. So when i write the multicols like this, the two equations in the multicol environment arent't at the same line. It looks really strange. Both cols are containing the same Text, only the equations are different. After the multicol environment, there has to be some other text.
I tried  a columnbreak together with the commend above. but it doesn't helped me. 
If you need to know, i use overleaf.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \underline{Fall 1: \(x<0\)}\\
    Die allgemeine Lösung der obigen Schrödingergleichung:
    \begin{align}
        \psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}
    \end{align}
    \vfill\null
    %\columnbreak
    \noindent
    \underline{Fall 2: \(x>0\)}\\
    Die allgemeine Lösung der obigen Schrödingergleichung:
    \begin{align}
        \psi(x)=Fe^{ikx}+Ge^{-ikx}
    \end{align}
\end{multicols}
```

I hope you have a hint for me...
Greetings ;-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that will allow others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: If you only want to align two lines of text and two equations side by side, I would usggest going for a `tabular` instead of the `multicols` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `tabularx` package, the `nccmath` package and its environment `fleqn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X@{\qquad}X @{}}
\underline{Fall 1: \(x<0\)}

Die allgemeine Lösung der obigen Schrödingergleichung:
    &   \underline{Fall 2: \(x>0\)} 

        Die allgemeine Lösung der obigen Schrödingergleichung:  \\
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
    \psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
    &   \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{align}
        \psi(x)=Fe^{ikx}+Ge^{-ikx}
        \end{align}
        \end{fleqn}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```